# How to calculate numbers of quarters between two dates in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to determine the number of quarters between two dates in google sheets with Q1 being Jan 1 2022 to March 31 2022 & so on for Q2, Q3, Q4.

For example: Date1: 06/14/2022  &  Date2: 10/12/2022, the result should be 3 i.e., Q2, Q3, Q4.

Any advise on how this can be achieved.

I tried something like below but doesnt work

```
=CEILING(((YEAR(V3)*12+MONTH(V3))-(YEAR(U3)*12+MONTH(U3)))/3)
```

Comment: will there be dates with different years? are quarters sstandard? Q1= 1/1 - 31/3 ?

Comment: @player0 No, there will be only 1 year (2021) and yes the quarters are standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple one in the same year, try

```
=int((month(V3)-1)/3)-int((month(U3)-1)/3)+1
```

or

```
=QUOTIENT(month(V3)-1,3)-quotient(month(U3)-1,3)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will work for any given date range:

Lets assume cell `A1` contains start date and cell `A2` contains end date.

First we need to calculate the first day of the next quarter (we will save the value in `B1`):

`=IF(AND(DAY(A1) = 1, MATCH(MONTH(A1), {1,4,7,10})), A1, Date(IF(MONTH(A1) >= 10, YEAR(A1) + 1, YEAR(A1)), IFS(MONTH(A1) < 4, 4, MONTH(A1) = 4, 7, MONTH(A1) = 5, 7, MONTH(A1) = 6, 7, MONTH(A1) = 7, 10, MONTH(A1) = 8, 10, MONTH(A1) = 9, 10, MONTH(A1) >= 10, 1), 1))`

Then, using `DATEDIFF` we will get the number of full quarters.

```
=IF(DAYS(A2, B1) < 0, 0, ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(B1, A2, "M")/3))
```

We can also merge the two formulas above into one formula that doesn't use temp cells:

`=IF(DAYS(A2, IF(AND(DAY(A1) = 1, MATCH(MONTH(A1), {1,4,7,10})), A1, Date(IF(MONTH(A1) >= 10, YEAR(A1) + 1, YEAR(A1)), IFS(MONTH(A1) < 4, 4, MONTH(A1) = 4, 7, MONTH(A1) = 5, 7, MONTH(A1) = 6, 7, MONTH(A1) = 7, 10, MONTH(A1) = 8, 10, MONTH(A1) = 9, 10, MONTH(A1) >= 10, 1), 1))) < 0, 0, ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(IF(AND(DAY(A1) = 1, MATCH(MONTH(A1), {1,4,7,10})), A1, Date(IF(MONTH(A1) >= 10, YEAR(A1) + 1, YEAR(A1)), IFS(MONTH(A1) < 4, 4, MONTH(A1) = 4, 7, MONTH(A1) = 5, 7, MONTH(A1) = 6, 7, MONTH(A1) = 7, 10, MONTH(A1) = 8, 10, MONTH(A1) = 9, 10, MONTH(A1) >= 10, 1), 1)), A2, "M")/3))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=ROUNDOWN(DATEDIF(A1,A2,"M")/3) +1
```

Where cell A1 contains any start date and cell A2 contains any end date.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"M")/3) +1
```

This variation will always use today's date as the end date.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A1:A10)&"×"&IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IF(SEQUENCE(1, 1000, 0)<=DAYS(B1:B10, A1:A10), A1:A10+SEQUENCE(1, 1000, 0), ), 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN({"1/1/", "1/4/", "1/7/", "1/10/"}&
 SEQUENCE(4, 1, 2020)&"×"&{"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"}), "×"), 2, 1))), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0)))
```

[image]